# Where did Mercurial install to?

Tags: installation, apt, mercurial

I used `sudo apt-get install mercurial` to install Hg.. where did it put the executable?  I need to specify the location in Netbeans.

Is there a general way to find where apt-get installs things?  (Before the install would be nice, too.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To list files installed by a package execute:

```
dpkg -L package
```

Also if the binary is at the search PATH you should be able to locate it with:

```
which binary_name
```

Comment: Awesome on both counts... thanks.  `/usr/bin/hg`

Comment: Just for completeness, the inverse operation is also extremely useful -- I have a program or file, I know where it is, what package installed it?  "dpkg -S <path/to/file>" will tell you.